# libjansi issue when trying to install Scala on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: scala, ubuntu-10.04, apt-get

when i do

```
apt-get install scala
```

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.   scala: Depends:
>   libjansi-java but it is not installable E: Broken packages

Though when I do apt-cache show scala I get

> Architecture: all Version: 2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu1 Depends: scala-library
>   (= 2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu1), openjdk-6-jre | java6-runtime Filename:
>   pool/universe/s/scala/scala_2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu1_all.deb

Comment: Is it a requirement to install it via apt-get?

Comment: not really a requirement but i like my packages handled that way (especially on my production servers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems a very very old Scala included in the default repository.

Follow these [instructions to install the Typesafe Stack](http://typesafe.com/stack/download#deb) with all the goodies. This is the official distribution of Scala and related tools.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

without any package names

Answer (score 0):

scala : Depends: libjansi-java but it is not installed
If you recently installed Scala and Java Background Processing is running wait for some time 10-20 mints and use

### sudo apt-get update

and after this time interval you can try to install whatever you wanted this dependency issue resolve automatically. its works